# XML serialization: instantiate derived class according to attribute value

Tags: c#, .net, xml

One more question on XML serialization. I have a `Base` class, and I have `Derived1` and `Derived2` classes inherited from it. I want to deserialize them from xml element `<base>` and I want to create `Derived1` instance if `<base attr="1">` or `Derived2` instance if `<base attr="2">`. How can I do it? Please, note that I use `XmlSerializes` and `XmlAttributeOverrides`. Thank you

Comment: Does my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I completely revised my answer to fit your exact situation. Assuming you have already correctly serialized your Base list, the code below should work.

I wouldn't normally recommend a switch statement because it violates OCP. Polymorphism is usually a better answer. But for a quick-and-dirty solution, and for a switch statement that has relatively few values (like your case), this will work.

Important note: The XML serializer will already deserialize to the correct derived class, assuming things were serialized correctly. But if for some reason that's not the case in your situation, then you need the rest of the code (foreach with switch statement).

```
private static void ImportDerivedClasses()
{
    List<Base> bases;
    string filePathAndName = @"c:\temp\SerializedBases.xml";

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePathAndName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Base>));
        bases = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream) as List<Base>;
    }

    // The rest of this is unnecessary if we originally serialized correctly.

    List<Base> deserializedBases = new List<Base>();

    foreach(Base baseClass in bases)
    {
        switch (baseClass.Attr)
        {
            case "1":
                deserializedBases.Add(new Derived1());
                break;
            case "2":
                deserializedBases.Add(new Derived2());
                break;
            default:
                // Log warning
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, down to the message to use when suppressing FxCop! Er, could you cut that down a bit for people who don't really know about your particular project?